# Python Error: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, parsing, split, typeerror

Open the file mbox-short.txt and read it line by line. When you find a line that starts with 'From ' like the following line:

```
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008
```

You will parse the From line using split() and print out the second word in the line (i.e. the entire address of the person who sent the message). Then print out a count at the end.

**Hint**: make sure not to include the lines that start with 'From:'.

Link for mbox-short.txt file:
 http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/mbox-short.txt

```
fopen = raw_input('Enter the file name you want to open: ')
fname = open(fopen)
line = 0
count = 0
pieces = 0
email = list()
for line in fname:
    lines = line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith('From '):
        continue
    pieces = line.split()
    print pieces[1]
print 'There were' ,count(pieces[1]), 'lines in the file with From as the first word
```

I managed to get the correct output, until the last print message.

Execution:

```
Enter the file name you want to open: mbox-short.txt

louis@media.berkeley.edu
zqian@umich.edu
rjlowe@iupui.edu
zqian@umich.edu
rjlowe@iupui.edu
cwen@iupui.edu
cwen@iupui.edu
gsilver@umich.edu
gsilver@umich.edu
zqian@umich.edu
gsilver@umich.edu
wagnermr@iupui.edu
zqian@umich.edu
antranig@caret.cam.ac.uk
gopal.ramasammycook@gmail.com
david.horwitz@uct.ac.za
david.horwitz@uct.ac.za
david.horwitz@uct.ac.za
david.horwitz@uct.ac.za
stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za
louis@media.berkeley.edu
louis@media.berkeley.edu
ray@media.berkeley.edu
cwen@iupui.edu
cwen@iupui.edu
cwen@iupui.edu

Traceback (most recent call last):
print 'There were' ,count(pieces[1]), 'lines in the file with From as   the first word'

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

**I am not sure why I am getting this Traceback.**

Comment: At the top of your script you have `count = 0`, which is not callable, i.e., function/class/etc. What did you expect that to do?

Comment: `count` is a variable, not a function. I think if you just use: `print 'There were' ,pieces[1], 'lines in the file with From as the first word'` it should work...

Comment: As the other answers have said: `count` is not a function, so I don't understand why you'd expect it to work.

Comment: @Reti43 I originally used count = 0 to count each line that i print in a for loop. But I took that part of the code out since it was not necessary. Thank You for pointing that out to me. I realize that is unnecessary code.

Comment: If you remove `count = 0` you'll get a `NameError` when you refer to `count` later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments in the question have mentioned, `count` is not listed as a function - instead, it's an `int`. You can't pass `pieces[1]` to it and expect it to magically increment itself.

If you really want the counts this way, simply update the count while looping through the file.

```
fopen = raw_input('Enter the file name you want to open: ')
fname = open(fopen)
line = 0 # unnecessary
count = 0 
pieces = 0 # also unnecessary
email = list() # also unnecessary
for line in fname:
    lines = line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith('From '):
        continue
    pieces = line.split()
    print pieces[1]
    count = count + 1 # increment here - counts number of lines in file
print 'There were', count, 'lines in the file with From as the first word
```

Comment: You're adding extra spaces in the output, by the way.

Comment: Edited. Thanks! I haven't used the clunky statement version of `print` in a while...

Comment: It would happen the same way in Python 3. The default separator is a space.

Answer (score 0):

`'int' object is not callable` because `count = 0` and then `count(pieces[1])`. You have an integer, and you are calling it. After this:

```
pieces = line.split()
print pieces[1]
```

Add this:

```
count += 1
```

And then change this:

```
print 'There were' ,count(pieces[1]),
```

To this:

```
print 'There were', count,
```

Comment: Thank you so much that helped me with majority of my problem.